# What if the words ‘son’ and ‘daughter’ in Germannic languages are cognates of (and Maybe originate from) forms for sun and morning?

Tags: relations

To name the gender of your offspring, why relate to sky terminology?

Son/Zoon/Sohn vs Sun/Zon/Sonne

Dochter/Tochter/Daughter vs 
Ochtend and Dageraad/Tag/Day

Compare this with:
Mother earth: matter
Father sky: feather

I would assume it to come from the metaphores for the parents: matter and feather.

So the family tree is based on the Ancient 
divinity family tree.

Earth (matter-mother) and sky feather-father produce Sun (Son) and dageraad (daybreak-daughter).

Compare nature with Greek andros (man) and neter (Ancient Egyptian god).

In my spare time I research unusual cognates based on the idea that the concrete world served as a metaphore for abstract ideas like human family relations in this case. I have to say by asking questions like this on the Linguistic Stack Exchange my reputation there was ruined by people who can not imagine such reasons for relations between words. I have hopes the philosophy community can provide insights that can help prove or disprove such relations.

Answer (score 3):

The roots are unrelated. (Btw questions of this type are easily resolved using a lexicon or Wiktionary.)

If you enjoy conceptual investigations of etymological roots you might be interested in Heidegger's *Introduction to Metaphysics*.

Comment: +1 Good answer but the question doesn't belong here.

Comment: The question does belong here because linguistics historically is part of the philosophical disciplines. I specifically ask pilosophers to answer the question, not schooled linguists who have a too narrow view on questions regarding the reasons why we say what we say.

Comment: @guest1806 Thank you for the answer. Simply staying the roots are unrelated and referring to lexicons is exactly not what is asked. This question is asked based on comparative etymology not historical linguistics. What if this method of finding cognates by different methods than historical linguistics, what rammifications would that have dor our understanding of the origin and use of language.

Comment: Wiktionary and lexicons do not look at contextual relationships based on metaphores for instance. Historical linguistics only looks at meaning, translations and sound changes limiting the range of possible word use changes. This limits the philosophy (love for wisdom) dramatically and suffocates pioneering work. The historical linguistic model is incomplete and insufficiënt to explain linguistics completely. Example, why would a word originate from Ancient Greek only because that is the language the word was first written down in.

Comment: Besides it being the lingua franca for many scientific words that does not mean a word or cognate always derived from Ancient Greek. Because a statue of a God is the oldest statue in the world, does not mean it was the first God worshipped or first worshipped in this culture. It is an assumption presented as science and allows for a lot of rubbish because comparative etymology provides other methods to show relations that may prove or disprove the historical linguistic conclusions.

Comment: This question really should be accepted as on topic. This touches the heart of philosophy. So please reason why to you it is off topic?

Comment: Geoff. - I certainly agree the question is asked from a position of little knowledge about the topic, but I didn't vote to close because serious philosophers (e.g. Heidegger) do think about historical linguistics. ——— Ajagar - if this is genuinely a topic that interests you, you need to get an introductory text on historical linguistics and the comparative method.  You don't have the proper tools to understand the answer to your question.

Comment: I don't know anything about this subject. I did a quick search of a couple of local libraries. There are books in metaphor in the philosophy section.  So why don't you do some library research in a real library?  Maybe you already have. Continue your research and write a book yourself.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant to write "on metaphor" above. Good luck.

Comment: @guest: You wrote; “Ajagar - if this is genuinely a topic that interests you, you need to get an introductory text on historical linguistics and the comparative method. You don't have the proper tools to understand the answer to your question.” I am working on a comparitive method using spelling similarities where both words share a similar idea within different meanings and contexts. I hypothesis that roots can go back to the letters/sounds in a word, so a word originally was a description. Gordon, Yes I will and hope to publish one day.